# Unable to integrate facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Hi All I'm creating a demo app in which i'm trying to integrate facebook login.
I've done everything I came up with but it's not working properly . One can login but it doesn't show any status/message.
This is My MainActivity :

```
package com.example.manishnegi.logindemo;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGIN SUCCESS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Status","Success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGIN CANCEL",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Status","Cancelled");
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LOGIN ERROR : "+exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("Status","Error");
            Log.e("Exception ",exception.getMessage());
            // App code
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
}
```

This is Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.manishnegi.logindemo" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

Ideally there should be one of the message success,cancelled or error, but it simply logs in without generating any message. May be I'm missing something please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have call `onActivityResult()` for forwarding the login results to the `callbackManager` created in `onCreate()`:-

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Every activity and fragment that you integrate with the `FacebookSDK` Login or Share should forward `onActivityResult` to the `callbackManager`.

If you want access facebook profile then must give `public_profile` permission in developer console.

And do this entry in `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderandyourappidfromfacebookconsole"
    android:exported="true" />
```

for more Info follow this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).
I hope this work for you. Good Luck

Comment: But if I'm not wrong then at least The Success message should get printed

Comment: Yeah. In my code I've written messages for all the possible scenarios i.e success,cancel and onError but none of the message gets printed. what to do?

Comment: first of all you call onActivityResult() in your activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96951/discussion-between-brucode-and-gargs).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

write this provider code into application tag of manifest

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider**your_facebook_app_id**"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: thanks for the response but how to add app id. after a period?

Comment: after a period?  - means ?

Comment: how to append the facebook_app_id in the given code. Period means '.'

Comment: if your app id=12345678 then set android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider12345678"

Comment: write code after intialize loginButton --    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday, user_photos"));

Comment: I've done that but right now i'm not willing to fetch any data. Can't I just simply log in and get the Success Message on my logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96950/discussion-between-brucode-and-vimal-gajera).